# Ansible: No package matching 'docker-ce' is available

Tags: docker, ansible

I have ansible playbook that suppose to install Docker on Oracle Cloud powered by Ampere (arm) that runs arm version of Ubuntu. The playbook is the following:

```
- name: Set sudo
  set_fact:
    ansible_become: yes
    ansible_become_method: sudo

- name: Docker installation - installing prerequisites
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    name:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - gnupg-agent
      - software-properties-common
    update_cache: yes

- name: Docker installation - Adding apt-key
  ansible.builtin.apt_key:
    url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg

- name: Docker installation - Adding docker repo
  ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
    repo: deb [arch=armhf] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ ansible_lsb.codename }} stable
    state: present
    update_cache: yes

- name: Update cache
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    update_cache: yes

- name: Docker installation - Installing Docker
  ansible.builtin.apt:
    name:
      - docker-ce
      - docker-ce-cli
      - containerd.io
    update_cache: yes
```

I posted that question on stackoverflow but was suggested to move here and add some information. One of those information is "What is the value of ansible_lsb.codename. I have added another small task so ansible prints the value of that variable. That part was placed directly before task tkat is causing the problem

```
- name: Print
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_lsb.codename }}"

The output is the following

ok: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] => {
    "msg": "mantic"
}
```

Following suggestion I have also checked the availability of armhf build but again as far as I can see such built is available

[image]

The problem is that for some reason the last task "Docker installation - Installing Docker" is throwing error

```
fatal: [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'docker-ce' is available"}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try debugging the system with a shell. Check the `sources.list` file that's created for the docker repo. Try updating package cache and installing "by hand", does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same issue! But my playbooks worked perfect a year ago. Wired things... I tried add repo manually to my hosts and everything ok. But not with ansible...

UPDATE:
I could install it with this config

```
- name: Install required system packages
  apt:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
  vars:
    packages:
      - apt-transport-https
      - ca-certificates
      - curl
      - software-properties-common

- name: Add Docker’s official GPG key
  apt_key:
    url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
    state: present

- name: Add Docker repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ ansible_distribution_release }} stable
    state: present

- name: Install Docker CE
  apt:
    name: docker-ce
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes

- name: Install Docker Compose
  get_url:
    url: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-{{ ansible_system }}-{{ ansible_userspace_architecture }}
    dest: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    mode: 'u+x,g+x'

- name: Verify Docker Compose installation
  command: docker-compose --version
  register: docker_compose_version
- debug:
    var: docker_compose_version.stdout_lines
```